# accessing a cherrypy app from browser

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cherrypy

I'm a cherrypy/aws newbie. I want to run a simple cherrypy application and access it from the browser. Here is my cherrypy code:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"

cherrypy.server.socket_host = '0.0.0.0'
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

here is a screenshot of my ec2 security settings:

[image]

This is what I type in the browser:

```
http://ec2-##-##-###-##.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

http://ec2-##-##-###-##.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.8080

http://ec2-##-##-###-##.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/8080

http://ec2-##-##-###-##.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
```

Please advice.

Comment: The first and last url there are the only valid ones.  Assuming those are the ports

Comment: pycherry says: "Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080" 
and chrome says "the site cannot be reached"

Comment: You've not set port 8080 to be open on the `0.0.0.0/0` subnet

Comment: cricket__007 that did the trick. You are the king, god and everything between.